# Find row matching two criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet with data similar to the following:

```
P1_ShipType         P2_ShipType         RoundTime
Kus_AssaultFrigate  Tai_AssaultFrigate  117
Kus_AssaultFrigate  Tai_AttackBomber    17
Kus_AssaultFrigate  Tai_Carrier         1191
Kus_AttackBomber    Tai_AssaultFrigate  2775
Kus_AttackBomber    Tai_AttackBomber    18
Kus_AttackBomber    Tai_Carrier         0
Kus_Carrier         Tai_AssaultFrigate  1354
Kus_Carrier         Tai_AttackBomber    8
Kus_Carrier         Tai_Carrier         0
```

How do I retrieve the "RoundTime" when P1_ShipType is Kus_AttackBomber and P2_ShipType is Tai_Carrier?

In SQL this is easy, but how do you do it in Excel?

I found a way to do it using formulas here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214142

But I am curious how I would achieve this using pivot tables or VBA. I need to be able to perform some math operations on the returned values as well.

Here is the UDF I design based on the answer given below. Thanks!

```
Function GetRoundTime(s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    'Need to find out what the last row is dynamically instead of hardcoding it at 1000
    For i = 2 To 1000
        If Worksheets(s3).Cells(i, "D").Value = s1 And Worksheets(s3).Cells(i, "I").Value = s2 Then
            GetRoundTime = CStr(Worksheets(s3).Cells(i, "K").Value)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    GetRoundTime = "Failed"
End Function
```

Comment: Sounds like a pivot table will help

Comment: pivot table: just create the same layout as your original data and filter for the desired values. VBA: it's not a script writing service, we don't write entire macros just to serve curiosity

Comment: If you change S3 in your UDF to the whole range where the values are, you can calculate your 1000 by counting the rows in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this small sub:

```
Sub FindFirstMatch()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rw As Long, rt As Long
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    s1 = "Kus_AttackBomber"
    s2 = "Tai_Carrier"

    For i = 2 To 10
        If Cells(i, "A") = s1 And Cells(i, "B") = s2 Then
            MsgBox "first match found on row # " & i & " with Round Time = " & Cells(i, "C").Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I used this code as a basis for creating a UDF. Thanks.

Comment: @posfan12  Very good ! _________________________

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an array formula :

```
{=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("Kus_AttackBomber Tai_Carrier",A:A&" "&B:B,0))}
```

should do what you want without having to use pivot tables or a macro